# Using Cells Function Prevents Closing

Tags: excel, vba

As part of a larger script, I'm trying to open an Excel workbook to update a range of cell values, then save and close Excel. The problem I am having is that if I use the Cells(row, col) function, an invisible instance of Excel remains open.

Interestingly, if I use the Range() function then Excel closes as expected.

I have done a fair amount of googling but nothing has fixed the issue - and I can't find anyone else who has had this specific issue with the Cells() function!

```
Sub testExcel()
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.worksheet
    Dim xRange As Excel.Range
    
    Dim filePath As String
    
    filePath = CurDir() & "\testExcel.xlsx"

    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
    xWs.Activate
    
    'Using Cells() prevents closing of excel
    Set xRange = Cells(5, 5)
    
    'If i were to use the Range instead, there is no problem:
    'Set xRange = xWs.Range("E5")
    
    xRange.Value = "Test"
    
    xWb.Save
    xWb.Close
    xExcelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

I would like to know why this is happening or how I can fix it.

Alternatively, because using Range() doesn't cause the same issue, is there a way to input row and column values into Range() using variables like the snippet below?

```
Dim row, col As Integer
row = 5
col = 5
xRange = Range(row,col)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the issue but I have absolutely no idea why it works. It would be really good if someone could explain why?

The problem disappears if I put the worksheet before Cells (or Range):

```
'Excel won't close:
Cells(row,col).Value = "test"
Range("A1").Value = "test"
'Excel will close:
xWs.Cells(row,col).Value = "test"
xWs.Range("A1").Value = "Test"
```

Comment: I recommend that you pay attention to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea "Select" was a thing. Very interesting and this will help my code.